# Multiple url thumbnail galerry

Tags: gallery, thumbnails

**Hi everyone. Please be advised, that I am still a beginner at CSS ;)**

I am working on making a clickable url thumbnail preview of my blog posts 
( or more precisely --> gallery of images with an description under or on them, that when clicked, takes you to the post itself)

, and wondering, about display of diffrent images instead of just one of the same, like in a screen below:

[Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z806E.png)

I already know, that I probably should use background-image:, instead of an image in HTML, but I can't figure out what is the best practice when it comes to doing so with many images.

1. Should i make a class or an id for every image div? Or can it be done by one or two classes?
2. What are your best practises when it comes to making a gallery of post thumbnails with url's?

Here's the code:

```css
 div.wrapper{
    width: ("275 + YOUR border-size" x 3)px;
     }
    div.image{
    background-image: url(..path to your img);
    float: left
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
    ... add all your imgs here
    <div style="clear: both"></div> //need this one here to make the wrapper extend 
</div>
```

***All help much appreciated :)***

Answer (score 0):

You could create an ID for all of them individually and assign them but as developers we should look to exterminate duplication.

Using just CSS and HTML it is nearly impossible to achieve this.

So we need the help of Javascript.

**Identifier**

We need something that can make each one special, something that can set them all apart, whether that's an ID or a class.

The syntax of the code that I'm about to write will look a bit crazy, but it works.

**Solution**

Using jquery also.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     //once the document/page has loaded run this code
         array = [filepath1,filepath2,filepath3];
         //hold all your file paths in an array
         for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
          //here we loop through the array and enclose each file path with an image tag
            $('.wrapper').html('<img class="image" src="'+array[i]+'.jpg" /><br>');
         }
     });
```

**HTML**

Your HTML will look like this

```
      <html lang="en">
           <head>
              <!--Include Javascript file you just made-->
              <script type="text/javascript" src="./file.js"></script>
              <!--Include jquery-->
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           </head>

           <body>
                <div class="wrapper"></div>
          </body>
      </html>
```